# Trying to add an eventListener to component, but it breaks my app

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an eventListener to component, but it breaks my app...

```
import "./button.scss";

document.getElementById('change-theme-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
   document.body.classList.toggle('pink-background');
});

const button = '<button id="change-theme-btn">Button</button>';

export default button;
```

Comment: how exactly is it `breaking` your app?

Comment: My bet is that addEventListener is not a function of null?  But yeah, OP needs to give us more information

Comment: I'm pretty sure you add even listener is running before your button is actually on the page. I would suggest putting it in a function and adding an onload to the button that references that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you add even listener is running before your button is actually on the page. I would suggest putting it in a function and adding a click to the button that references that function. See below.

```
import "./button.scss";
window.buttonClick = function(e) {
  document.body.classList.toggle('pink-background');
};

const button = '<button onclick="buttonClick()" id="change-theme-btn">Button</button>';

export default button;
```

Comment: Needs to be window.buttonClick = function () and then it works!

Comment: Sorry, been working in React and haven't had to worry about that! Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add listener to DOM node that's not in the DOM yet. You should have error that you can't call addEventListener of null because getElementById will not find the button. To go around this you can use event delegation:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    var matches = element.msMatchesSelector || element.matches;
    if (matches.call(element, "#change-theme-btn")) {
       document.body.classList.toggle('pink-background');
    }
});
```